# Upload file contents using cURL

Tags: post, curl

I have a script with which I POST data to a server using cURL.  When I use an HTML form to POST the same data, the POST looks something like this and all is well:

```
description=Something&name=aName&xml=wholeBiunchOfData&xslt=moreData
```

The XML and XSLT are large and change; I would prefer to maintain them in external files.  However, the following does not work as I expect;

```
curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --location --output NUL ^
 --data "name=aName&description=Something" ^
    --data "xml=@localFile.xml" ^
 --data "xslt=@localFile.xslt" ^
 http://someUrl.html
```

I have tried various combinations of the @ and local files without success.  How do I POST the contents of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying the following:

```
curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --location --output NUL ^
 --data "name=aName&description=Something" ^
    --data-urlencode "xml@localFile.xml" ^
 --data-urlencode "xslt@localFile.xslt" ^
 http://someUrl.html
```

XML (including stylesheets) will need to be URL-encoded before being made part of a URL.

You can also use `--trace-ascii -` as an additional parameter to dump the input and output to standard out for further debugging, and you can find more information on the main [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the man page it looks like the --data @file syntax does not permit for a variable name, it must be in the file.  http://paulstimesink.com/2005/06/29/http-post-with-curl/.  You could also try using a backtick

```
curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --location --output NUL ^
 --data "name=aName&description=Something" ^
 --data "xml=`cat localFile.xml`" ^
 --data "xslt=`cat someFile.xml`" ^
 http://someUrl.html
```

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Looks like it's moved to http://paulstimesink.com/2005/06/29/http-post-with-curl/.